# Python: io.TextIOWrapper illegal newline

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to set the newline character for SiRF binary messages, but the IO wrapper doesn't seem to accept the newline chars.

Code:

```
import serial
import io

port = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=4800, timeout=2)
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(port, port), newline='\xb0\xb3')
```

Output:

```
>>> sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(port, port, 1), newline='\xb3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: illegal newline value: �
>>>
```

Note: It does accept '\x0d'

Comment: If you are producing binary messages, why are you using a `TextIOWrapper()` here?

Comment: pyserial says to use it when changing the EOL character

Comment: Right, but only within the confines of what the library supports, which is what current OSes use for line endings. One of `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`.

Comment: That also talks about reading lines, which implies working with text, not binary data.

Comment: So, there is no way to read a line of binary data?

Comment: A 'line' is a textual concept, binary data is usually handled in chunks (where the stream might provide information on how long the next chunk is going to be). So no, because binary data, on the whole, doesn't use delimiters to denote units, there is no `.readline()` implementation for binary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not just use any character as the newline. From the [`io.TextIOWrapper()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

> *newline* controls how line endings are handled. It can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`.

You'll have to handle those bytes manually instead of a newline, directly.

Comment: I'm trying to read lines, not write them. Do I have to manually write a readline() function?

Comment: If this is a binary format, you'll have to find a library that specifically handles parsing such messages, or write your own. Read the binary stream and go from there, yes.

Comment: Actually combining the "readLine()" function with other processing is going to clean up my functions a little bit. Thanks for the help.